# Making N baht using only 9 baht and 10 baht coins

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The Thai government decides to issue coins of 9 baht. Show that, for all sufficiently large numbers N you can make N baht using only 9 baht and 10 baht coins.

Comment: This is the [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). $71$ is the largest sum you cannot obtain.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that all of the values from 72 to 80 can be expressed with 8 coins.

Use that as a base case, and prove that every higher value can be achieved using induction. (Note that if $n - 9$ is expressible, then $n$ is as well.)

Comment: Don't you mean n = 9? Or is it n - 9?

Comment: I definitely meant $n - 9$.

Comment: The number of elements for which you can not make change is:$\frac{1}{2}*(10 - 1)*(9 - 1) = 36 $